# Python expression evaluation

Tags: python, expression

Why does python obtain such a result?

```
>>> 1 in [] == False
False
```

Obviously, `'1 in []'` is evaluated to `False`, and `'False == False'` is evaluated to `True`. And `1 in ([] == False)` is not valid expression.

On the other hand `'(1 in []) == False'` is evaluated to `True`, but I still do not understand why `'1 in [] == False'` is evaluated to `False`,

Comment: The expression should be *(1 in []) == False*

Comment: I think `1 in [] == False` is the same as `1 in [] and [] == False`, Similar to python letting you do `10 <= x <= 50`. It converts `1 in x == False` into `1 in x and x == False`. Comparison with False won't even happen if first expression is false. Edit: Typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python interprets `1 in [] == False` as

`1 in [] AND [] == False`.  Both of which are `False`.

Also `1 in [1] == False` is `False` since

`1 in [1] AND [1] == False` generates `True` and `False`.  `True` and `False` gives us `False`.